# Azure APIM policy with dynamic claims in token validation

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-api-management

I am using APIM to expose multiple endpoints from a range of different Azure Functions as operations in the same API. Different operations in this API might have different audiences (`aud`) in the token based on which function is behind that particular operation.

What might differ though, is that the authorized party (`azp`) is not always the same. According to the [OIDC documentation](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDTokenValidation), this should then also be verified. In some cases, requests originate from a single page application where the token is issued on behalf of a user that signed in. In other cases, the request originates from someone integrating towards my APIs using a principal instead and a `client_credentials` grant type.

What I want to achieve is to have as simple a policy as possible, and still allow a range of different `azp` claims for a single `aud` claim. This is how I'm currently doing this:

```xml
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
    <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantId}}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    <required-claims>
        <claim name="aud" match="all">
            <value>{{target-api-clientId}}</value>
        </claim>
        <claim name="azp" match="any">
            <value>{{spa-clientId}}</value>
            <value>{{integrator-clientId1}}</value>
            <value>{{integrator-clientId2}}</value>
        </claim>
    </required-claims>
</validate-jwt>
```

However, this doesn't scale very well and forces me to keep duplicate policies between environments and for each new allowed authorized party I must add a new row in the `azp` claim section as a well as new named values.

The [documentation specifies that there is a `separator` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validate-jwt-policy#claim-attributes) for the claim element, but as far as I can tell, this only splits the claim in the incoming token on that separator character and I always only have a single `aud` and `azp` claim in the incoming tokens.

Is there any way for me to achieve a single API baseline policy, where each operation could set its expected required parameters? Something along these lines:

**API base policy**

```xml
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
    <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantId}}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    <required-claims>
        <claim name="aud" match="all">
            <value>@((string)context.Variables["aud"])</value>
        </claim>
        <claim name="azp" match="any">
            @((List<string>)context.Variables["azp"])
        </claim>
    </required-claims>
</validate-jwt>
```

**Operation specific policy**

```xml
<set-variable name="aud" value="{{allowed-aud-for-this-operation}}" />
<set-variable name="azp" value="{{list-of-allowed-authorized-parties-for-this-operation}}" />
<base />
```

To further clarify what the infrastructure looks like and where requests might originate from, this might shine some light:
[image: apim infra]

Is there any way to achieve dynamic token evaluation like this? If not, what are my other options? Am I approaching this problem the right way, or should I rethink?